# Does OpenLayers have the ability to mask a raster with another layer?

Tags: openlayers-2

Does OpenLayers have the ability to mask (in the GIS sense) one raster layer by another vector (or raster) layer?

For instance this would be the ability to show only the parts of one layer that are spatially coincident with another.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is better handled on the server-side.  For us we are going to use MapServer's new mask functionality at the Layer level. See http://mapserver.org/trunk/development/rfc/ms-rfc-79.html.

Hope this helps anyone else w/ the same question.